# Do we really need to use bootstrap.js functionality / file while using bootstrap.css in styling webpages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Do we really need to use bootstrap.js functionality / file while using bootstrap.css in styling webpages. If required optionally, what are the advantages of using the same?

Comment: How about reading the documentation of bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

The `CSS` file contains all the styling that makes Bootstrap look like Bootstrap.

The `JS` file contains all the `JavaScript` needed to render some graphic components and animations.

While you can indeed get away in certain scenarios by only including the CSS file, it all depends on the components you're planning to use - tooltips, modals, and dropdowns for example, utilise the JS file.

Answer (score 1):

The only goal to use bootstrap.js is fast implementation  of dropdowns, modals and etc functions.

A lot of Angularjs developers (for example) didn't use native js at all (the use special lib - [bootstrap ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (for angularjs only)).

But if you use JQuery-like code style - ask your self - why not? Much better to use native lib, then implement it functions by yourself/